# Flutter FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

I am initializing the variable named _sum = 0.0 , and in the FutureBuilder's Connection.default state i am updating it inside the ListView.builder. After the ListView.Builder Widget , there is a Text Widget , where i am displaying the value of this variable _sum . But i am always getting the value as 0.0 , why is it so ?

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:cakeapp/models/AllProductsList.dart';
import 'package:cakeapp/models/ProductModel.dart';
import 'package:cakeapp/models/ShoppingCartNumberInfo.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class UserCartPage extends StatefulWidget 
{
  @override
  _UserCartPageState createState() => _UserCartPageState();
}

class _UserCartPageState extends State<UserCartPage> {
  Future<allProductsList> getCartList;
  List<Product> _elements;
  double _sum = 0;

  Future<allProductsList> _fetchAllProducts() async {
    final SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String apiToken = sharedPrefs.getString('apiToken');
    String userMobile = sharedPrefs.getString('userMobile');
    Response response = await get(
        "https://7facfb64f1d9.ngrok.io/api/getCart/?phone=$userMobile",
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $apiToken',
        });
    List<dynamic> allProducts = json.decode(response.body);
    allProductsList cartProducts = allProductsList.fromJson(allProducts);
    return cartProducts;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCartList = _fetchAllProducts();
    getCartList.then((value) {
      _elements = value.allProducts;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        title: Text('Cart Page'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: getCartList,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            _sum = 0.0;
            print("Cart List 1212 Build Ran Again");
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.none:
              case ConnectionState.waiting:
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              default:
                return Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 9,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: _elements.length,
                          itemBuilder: (ctxt, index) {
                             _sum += _elements[index].price;
                              print(_sum);
                            return Consumer<ShoppingCartNumberInfo>(
                                builder: (context, value, child) {
                              return Card(
                                  child: ListTile(
                                leading: ClipRRect(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                                  child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                    placeholder: (context, url) =>
                                        const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                    imageUrl: _elements[index].url,
                                    height: 80.0,
                                    width: 80.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                title: Text(_elements[index].name),
                                subtitle: Column(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text(_elements[index].description),
                                    Row(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        IconButton(
                                          icon: Icon(Icons.remove_circle,
                                              color: Colors.black),
                                          onPressed: () {},
                                        ),
                                        Container(
                                          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                                Radius.circular(15.0)),
                                            border: Border.all(width: 2),
                                          ),
                                          child: Text(
                                            "1",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 15.0,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        IconButton(
                                          icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle,
                                              color: Colors.black),
                                          onPressed: () {},
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                                trailing: IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.remove_circle),
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                  onPressed: () async {
                                    SharedPreferences prefs;
                                    prefs =
                                        await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                                    String apiToken =
                                        prefs.getString('apiToken');
                                    int product_id = _elements[index].id;
                                    setState(() {
                                      value.removeCartItem(_elements[index].id);
                                      _elements.removeAt(index);
                                    });
                                    http.post(
                                      'https://7facfb64f1d9.ngrok.io/api/removeCartItem',
                                      headers: {
                                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                                        'Authorization': 'Bearer $apiToken',
                                      },
                                      body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
                                        'mobile': prefs.getString("userMobile"),
                                        'product_id': product_id.toString()
                                      }),
                                    );
                                  },
                                ),
                              ));
                            });
                          }),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                        child: Card(
                          elevation: 5,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                            child: Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 2,
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Total Price : ",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 1,
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Rs $_sum",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Also, when i removing the initializing part from the FutureBuilder Widget i.e when i removed the _sum= 0.0 , then the value of _sum is displayed properly .
Also , what ever i am assigning the value to the _sum variable that exact value gets printed inside the text of the Text Widget. If, i am assigning the value ,say for example 12, then that value gets printed inside the text. Why is it so ? Please help.

Comment: Finally,  i solved the problem.

Comment: You should post the answer and accept it so it will be helpfull to others :)